Measurability of sets under measurable function.
Let $E \subset [0, 1]^2$ that is measurable and consider $E_y = \{x: (x, y) \in E\}$. We can then write $$E = \bigcup_{y \in Y} (E_y \times \{y\}).$$ Consider a measurable function $T:[0, 1] \to [0, 1]$. Form the set $$D = \bigcup_{y \in Y} ((E_y + T(y))\times \{y\}).$$ Can we conclude that $D$ is measurable? I am having difficulties coming up with an argument about this. Don't even know if this is true or not, but would welcome any input.

You could try looking at $D$ as the preimage of $E$ under the action of $-T$, i.e. under $(x,y)\mapsto(x-T(y),y)$, which changes the question to whether that function is measurable.

And it seems to be, because both its components are measurable: $(x,y)\mapsto x-T(y)$ is measurable as a composition of $(x,y)\mapsto x-y$ (continuous) and $(x,y)\mapsto (x,T(y))$ (measurable because is measurable component-wise). If this looks right to you, I'll write it as an answer.

@Al.G. note that for a measurable function only preimages of Borel sets are measurable. Hence your reasoning works only if $E$ is Borel.

I appreciate the comments, I believe I understand. It makes me wonder, under the condition that $E$ is Borel can we show that $D$ is Borel if and only if $T$ is measurable? I will try.

@Kulisty it seems I've completely missed that in my measure theory course. I expected that a "measurable function f:R→R" means just measurable w.r.t. $\mathbb R$ as a Lebesgue-measure space, but as someone puts it explicitly on physics forums, it only means a Lebesgue-to-Borel measurable function. I'll think about extending the argument for non-Borel $E$.

@RKDMS, not really. We can show that $D$ is measurable under the assumption that $E$ is Borel and $T$ is measurable. I don't know the solution for non-Borel $E$, but I would expect counterexamples.
